# mysql select count from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, count, numbers, row

If I have two tables job, employee.
I need to select all from job and append employee count for each job.

Supposed Result

```
job table
+-------------+-------------+
| id          | name        |
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | Teacher     |
+-------------+-------------+
| 2           | Engineer    |
+-------------+-------------+
| 3           | Programmer  |
+-------------+-------------+

employee table
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id          | name        |   job_id    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | employee N  |      1      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2           | employee N  |      2      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 3           | employee N  |      3      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 4           | employee N  |      1      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 5           | employee N  |      3      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 6           | employee N  |      1      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to select all from job and append employee count for each job.

Supposed Result

```
Result table
+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| id          | name        |employee count|
+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1           | Teacher     |      3       |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 2           | Engineer    |      1       |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 3           | Programmer  |      2       |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use left join : )

```
SELECT job.id, job.name, count( * ) AS 'employee count'
FROM job
LEFT JOIN employee 
ON job.id = employee.job_id
GROUP BY job.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `INNER JOIN` to join the tables, then `GROUP BY` to group on the job id. Finally use `COUNT()` to get a count of each group

```
SELECT job.id, job.name, count(*) AS employee_count
FROM job
INNER JOIN employee 
  ON job.id = employee.job_id
GROUP BY job.id
```

You can see it live here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d59c1/1